# Where and Not in Rails' active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a table with the following fields
`bought_at` - A null date
`owned` - A null boolean

I want to simulate the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE bought_at IS NULL AND owned <> 1
```

I've tried

```
.where('bought_at IS NULL AND owned <> 1')
.where(bought_at: nil).not(owned: 1) #fails
.where(bought_at: nil).where.not(owned: 1)
```

And a few other possibilities similar to that (like `rewhere`) 
All result sets come empty. But if I try `owned: 1` or `owned = 1` it works fine.

Is there something wrong with my code? Is there something I am missing?

@edit

Turns out the problem wasn't related with ror. The query was evaluating as following:

`... AND owned <> 1` and THIS was the problem.

I still don't know why, but I think it was related with the negation of a NULL field. Since `owned` could be NULL, and in fact it was sometimes, I should always use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` and probably the engine was trying to use this operator '<>' on a NULL value.

Solution:

`... AND (owned = 0 OR owned IS NULL)`

in termos of ROR

`.where(bought_at: nil, owned: [0,nil]')`

Comment: hard to comment without seeing the rest of the code but .where('bought_at IS NULL AND owned <> 1') should work. What does your resulting sql query look like?

Comment: What query is this generating? You'll see that in `log/development.log`. Always keep that open when you're doing development, it's invaluable.

Comment: To be clear, when you run the SQL directly results are returned? You can tack `.to_sql` onto each of those where examples to see what it's going to do in the database.